# How does tf.dataset interact with keras.conv1D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using tf 1.15, i'm trying to make a regression task using a signal.

First of all i load my signals into the pipeline, i have several files, here i simulate the loading using a np.zeros to make the code usable by you.
Every file has this shape (?, 75000, 3), where ? is a random number of elements, 75000 is the number of samples in each element and 3 is the number of signals.

Using the tf.data i unpack them and i get a dataset who output signals with this shape (75000,), and i use them in my keras model.

Everything should be fine until i create the keras model, i copied my input pipeline because during my tests i got different errors using a generic tf.data.dataset or using the dataset built in this way.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# called in the dataset pipeline
def my_func(x):
    p = np.zeros([86, 75000, 3])
    x = p[:,:,0]
    y = p[:, :, 1]
    z = p[:, :, 2]
    return x, y, z

# called in the dataset pipeline
def load_sign(path):
    func = tf.compat.v1.numpy_function(my_func, [path], [tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64])
    return func

# Dataset pipeline
s = [1, 2]  # here i have the file paths, i simulate it with numbers
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE  
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(s)
# ds = ds.map(load_sign, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
ds = ds.map(load_sign, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).unbatch()
itera = tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(ds)
ABP, ECG, PLETH = itera.get_next() 

# Until there everything should be fine
# Here i create my convolutional network
signal = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,75000), dtype='float32')
x = tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, (1), strides=1, padding='same')(signal)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(75000)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=signal, outputs=x, name='resnet18')

# And finally i try to insert my signal into model
logits = model(PLETH)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.

Why? And how can i make it works?
Also the input size of my net should be this one according the documentation:

> 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, steps, input_dim)

What is the steps? In my case i assume it should be (batch_size, 1, 75000), right?

Comment: Your data has a shape of ( 86 , 75000 , 3 ) as observed in the code. The Input Layer should have `shape=( 75000 , 3 )`

Comment: When i load the file i have an input with dimension (86,75000,3), but i pass to my model only PLETH who has shape (75000,).